# Ingesar datos a tabla jsp

Tags: java, base-de-datos, array, webservice

Buenas Tardes .

Actualmente me encuentro realizando una programa  ,el cual tiene un LinkedList , al momento de querer aplicar el Method lista.contains("Mario") me regresa false ,cabe destacar que la lista la lleno de acuerdo a una clase de la siguiente forma ;

```
lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("Fifa 2017", "Deporte",120,"5","A"));
        lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("Halo", "Accion", 295,"2","B"));
        lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("PES 2014", "Deportes", 309,"4","C"));
        lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("Gears ", "Accion", 409,"3","B"));
        lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("Mario", "Fantasia", 509,"1","A"));
        lista.add(new VideojuegoBean("Mario Word", "Fantasia", 609,"4","C"));
```

Por lo cual tengo entendido deberia regresarme true ya que se encuentra en  la lista si lo contiene ,los demas datos entre parentesis son parte de los atributos de la clase VideojuegoBean , Cabe resaltar que si aplico la función

```
form.getLista().indexOf("Mario");
```

Debería regresar el index pero me regresa -1  y creo que esto sucede por que no se encuentra .

Ya trate de probar varias formas pero ninguna logra determinar si la lista contiene algún elemento .

Ojala Puedan guiarme para saber si estoy utilizando mal algún método .

La vista del lista se muestra asi ;

```
VideojuegoBean{titulo=Fifa 2017, genero=Deporte, cantidadJugadores=5, clasificacion=A, codigo=120}
VideojuegoBean{titulo=Halo, genero=Accion, cantidadJugadores=2, clasificacion=B, codigo=295}
VideojuegoBean{titulo=PES 2014, genero=Deportes, cantidadJugadores=4, clasificacion=C, codigo=309}
VideojuegoBean{titulo=Gears , genero=Accion, cantidadJugadores=3, clasificacion=B, codigo=409}
VideojuegoBean{titulo=Mario, genero=Fantasia, cantidadJugadores=1, clasificacion=A, codigo=509}
VideojuegoBean{titulo=Mario Word, genero=Fantasia, cantidadJugadores=4, clasificacion=C, codigo=609
```

Comment: Me ha vuelto a pasar, respondo a la pregunta y luego me pregunto qué clase de usuario eres. Veo por tu perfil que sólo haces preguntas y que, cuando te responden, no correspondes con la comunidad proporcionando feedback (marcando las respuestas correctas, o explicando qué es lo que no te funciona, etc.). Así que borro mi respuesta (me había quedado monísima, una pena) hasta que vea que marcas como correctas las respuestas (que se lo merezcan) a tus anteriores preguntas. Si en alguna pregunta no hay respuesta correcta, la puedes escribir tu mismo si ya la sabes.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres ?

Comment: Que pides, pero cuando tienes la solución no indicas si funciona, si no funciona... Revisa el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver cómo funciona este sitio.

Comment: Ok,Esta bien :) , Gracias por el comentario ,Saludos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, tu problema no tiene nada que ver con JSPs, bases de datos, arrays ni webservices. Si titulas y catalogas adecuadamente tus preguntas, será más fácil que encuentren respuesta. Y te recomiendo empezar a programar con Java SE (sin añadir las complejidades de JSPs o BD) antes de intentar hacer cosas más complicadas.

El problema es que lo que estás insertando en la lista instancias de `VideojuegoBean` y luego buscas una instancia de `String`. Cuando haces una búsqueda, el último paso<sup>1</sup> será comparar ambos objetos llamando al `equals` de uno de ellos para ver si devuelve `true`.

Hay dos posibilidades:

- que la instrucción sea `"Mario".equals(new VideojuegoBean("Mario", "xxxx"))`, que devolverá siempre `false`, y eso no se puede cambiar (requeriría cambiar la definición de `equals` de `String`, lo cual no sólo es imposible sino que muy peligroso.
- que la instrucción sea `((new VideojuegoBean("Mario", "xxxx")).equals("Mario")`. Aquí, en la implementación de `VideojuegoBean`, podrías hacer que la implementación de `equals`, si se compara con un `String`, equivalga a la comparación con el título. Pero es ***ALTAMENTE DESACONSEJABLE***, ya que entonces tienes que `"Mario".equals(unObjeto)` no es igual que `unObjeto.equals("Mario")`, lo cual va contra las especificaciones de Mario.
- Además, como esa instrucción se ejecuta como parte del API, nunca sabrás cuál de las dos se va a ejecutar.

Solución:

Pues para empezar, ya que estás empezando, el método antiguo que es iterar por la lista (usa un `Iterator` mejor); para cada videojuego obtienes su título y entonces comparas con "Mario".

```
 Iterator<VideojuegoBean> it = lista.iterator();
 VideojuegoBean encontrado = null;
 while ((it.hasNext() && (encontrado == null)) {
   VideojuegoBean vb = it.next();
   if ("Mario".equals(vb.getTitulo()) {
     encontrado = vb;
   }
 }
```

Si tienes Java 8, una vez que tengas más facilidad con el Java puedes usar *streams*, que permiten hacer lo mismo con algo menos de código.

---

<sup>1</sup>En según que subclases de `Collection` también tendrás que hacer que el `hashCode` sea coherente.

<sup>2</sup>Mayúsculas, negritas, cursiva... ¿me dejo algo para mostrar la mala idea que sería?